# Is it an issue when I change the IPv4 address of my SMTP server?

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server

I have a postfix/dovecot setup for a personal mail account. It's really just a one-man mail setup.

Now I want to move my setup to a new VPS which means it'd get a new IPv4 address. My concern is that I'm getting blacklisted because I use a new address. Is that a legit concern or am I just fine using whatever IP address as long as my (r)DNS records are fine?

---

To answer [anx'](https://serverfault.com/users/250204/anx) question: Why the one-man setup?
Privacy. One account per service.

```
stackexchange@brettetete.foo  
twitter@brettetete.foo  
github-account1@brettetete.foo  
github-anotheraccount@brettetete.foo  
...
```

Comment: You may get an IP address that was used by a spammer. I'd check some reputation sights like those listed in https://sendgrid.com/blog/5-ways-check-sending-reputation/. You'll be subject to greylisting so configure your mail server to retry sending and don't expect your mail to be delivered nearly instantly.

Answer (score 3):

Adding an DNS SPF record for new IP before you make the transition for outbound mail may help. I suspect you won't have much control over your IP, so if it has previously been associated with spammers you'll have to wait its reputation to improve by being a model netizen, or take another roll of the dice.